# Issue with grey field on logo in ABS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image: picture showing the issue]

Hi.

I have a problem with styling ABS. As you can see, it runs well on S3 (amazingly enough..) but on the Nexus 4 and 5, a grey field appears. I don't want this field, and after spending more time on it than I am willing to admit, I am now asking here for help.

Here is my code:

```
// Setup ABS
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);     
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_actionbar));
```

Does anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution.

The solution was to call

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

in onCreate.